# Editable UITableView with a textfield on each cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am new to the iOS world and I want to know how to make a `UITableView` with custom cells that look and behave like the one you have when you try to configure some WiFi connexion on your device. (You know the `UITableView` with cells containing `UITextField`s with blue font where you set up the ip address and all that stuff... ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make a custom cell layout do involve a bit of coding, so I hope that dosen't frighten you.

First thing is creating a new `UITableViewCell` subclass. Let's call it `InLineEditTableViewCell`. Your interface `InLineEditTableViewCell.h` could look something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InLineEditTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *propertyTextField;

@end
```

And your `InLineEditTableViewCell.m` could look like this:

```
#import "InLineEditTableViewCell.h"

@implementation InLineEditTableViewCell

@synthesize titleLabel=_titleLabel;
@synthesize propertyTextField=_propertyTextField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Here you layout your self.titleLabel and self.propertyTextField as you want them, like they are in the WiFi settings.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_titleLabel release], _titleLabel = nil;
    [_propertyTextField release], _propertyTextField = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Next thing is you set-up your `UITableView` as you normally would in your view controller. When doing this you have to implement the `UITablesViewDataSource` protocol method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Before inserting your implementation for this, remember to `#import "InLineEditTableViewCell"` in your view controller. After doing this the implementation is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InLineEditTableViewCell *cell = (InLineEditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your-static-cell-identifier"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[InLineEditTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"your-static-cell-identifier"] autorelease];
    }

    // Setup your custom cell as your wish
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Your title text";
}
```

That's it! You now have custom cells in your `UITableView`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks For your help. Actually I am not afraid of coding, I am not good at manipulating graphic elements :)